# Java: mutate an instance field

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

In the following example code, how do I mutate the instance field `var1` while not changing the `initialVal1` in the constructor (`var2`)? - should I make a copy using `Arrays.copyOf`?

```
public class Test
{
 private int[] var1;
 private int[] var2;

 public Test(int[] initialVal1)
 {
  var1 = initialVal1;
  var2 = initialVal1;
 }

 private void int mutateVar1()
 {
  this.var1[0] = 100;  // change the value at index 0 to 100 in var1 array, this also changes initialVal[0], right?
 }

 private int getSumOfInitial()
 { 
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < var2.length; i++) // but at this point, the initialVal[0] has also been mutated to 100.
   {
     sum += var2[i]
   }
   return sum;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Yes , you have to make an arraycopy..or in this case you can `clone`

Comment: The `getSumOfInitial` method won't compile since initialVal1 is not within scope in the method.  `initialVal1` is an argument passed to the constructor and will be out of scope once the constructor executes

Comment: Either you can clone or deeply copied collection(array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var1` and `initialVal` aren't arrays - they're just variables. Their values *refer* to an array... and they both refer to the *same* array. It's like having two pieces of paper both of which have the same house address on. Any changes you make to the house having followed the address on one piece of paper will obviously be visible if you then use the other piece of paper to visit the house again. I know this sounds like pedantry, but when you differentiate between variables, their values, and objects life becomes a lot clearer in my experience.

If you want two independent arrays, you need to do that deliberately. For example, you could change the constructor body to:

```
var1 = initialVal1.clone();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to clone, cause both are referring to the same `array`.

```
public Test(int[] initialVal1)
 {
  var1 = initialVal1.clone();// or Arrays.copyOf(initialVal1,initialVal1.length);
 }
```

Also you have a mistake in `getSumOfInitial` have to replace `initialVal1` to `var1`

```
private int getSumOfInitial()
 { 
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < var1.length; i++) // but at this point, the var1[0] has also been mutated to 100.
   {
     sum += var1[i]
   }
  }
```

Comment: please note that `clone();` can be safely used only on arrays - do not try cloning objects other than arrays it can lead to severe errors. http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71

Comment: @smajlo: That entirely depends on the type. It's misleading to claim that you can *only* use `clone()` safely on arrays. In many cases it can be hard to implement properly, but that's a long way from saying that's *always* the case.

Comment: You are completly right, but author of question seems to be very little experienced in java, so for now the best advice for him is to avoid using it.

Comment: @smajlo if the array is with mutable objects , you have to `clone` properly cause it will be only a shallow copy. In this case works cause it's with primitive types.

Comment: @smajlo That is pretty bad advice you shouldn't avoid methods because you are inexperienced.  You should investigate them and learn how to use them properly, not avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, `var1` is in fact another reference to the same array referenced by `initialVal1`, so as you said, changing an element in one would effect the other.

Copying the entire array with `Arrays.copyOf()` should do the trick, but it's wasteful.
If memory performance is an issue here, you should implement some sort of copy-on-write array.

Comment: what do you mean by copy-on-write array? you mean using a for-loop to copy every element from initialVal1? Please include an example. thanks

Comment: No. Copy-on-write is an approach to save only the values you've changed, and take the ones you haven't from `initialVal1`. Here's an implementation using an `ArrayList`, for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html